# passing the value of a uitextfield from a view to another

Tags: xcode, uitextfield

I want to pass the value entered in a UITextfield into another view. and this value shud appear in the UItextfield of second view. IBoutlet,propery,synthesize everything is written correctly. still i am not getting the value in the second view.
My code,
from first view it is passing like this
    firstview.txtname1.text=name1.text;
from second view it is accepting like this
    player_name1.text=txtname1.text; 
can anybody tell me where i went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to declare the property and synthesize in the secondviewcontroller.

in secondview.h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *str;
```

in secondview.m

```
@synthesize str;
```

And then when you are going from first view to second view do like this.

```
    secondviewobj.name = textfield.text;
```